# Consecutive output in a column of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a column in my data frame as "Product", I want to **couple** the new column by the products (p1,p2). It shows the first "p1" then "p2", and continues this combination. My desirable output is shown in the column of 'Desirable Result':

| Product | Desirable Result |
| --- | --- |
| p2 |  |
| p1 | p1 |
| p1 |  |
| NaN |  |
| p2 | p2 |
| p2 |  |
| p1 | p1 |
| p1 |  |
| p2 | p2 |

Comment: can you add some more explanation about what a `first` signal is?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = df["Product"].ffill()
df["Result"] = df.groupby((x != x.shift(1)).cumsum())["Product"].transform(
    lambda x: [x.iat[0], *[""] * (len(x) - 1)]
)

# remove first p2 (if any):
df["Result"] = df["Result"] * (df["Product"] == "p1").cumsum().gt(0)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Product Desirable Result Result
0      p2                        
1      p1               p1     p1
2      p1                        
3                                
4      p2               p2     p2
5      p2                        
6      p1               p1     p1
7      p1                        
8      p2               p2     p2
```